# The way to compute off-diagonal terms of a square matrix

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix `X` and use it to compute the square matrix in MATLAB: `S=X*X'`. I need to find only off-diagonal elements of `S`.

I understand how to do this for the diagonal: `sum(X.*X,1)`. Is there the similar way to find off-diagonal elements by vectorization?

Comment: Welcome to the site! With `S=X*X'` you get the off-diagonal _and_ the diagonal entries. If `X` has `n` rows, avoiding to compute the diagonal terms would only save `n` terms out of `n^2` in total. You could save an additional factor of `2` due to symmetry. Is it worth it? What size is your matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the elements of the `d`-th off-diagonal this should work:

```
sum(X(:,1:end-d).*X(:,1+d:end),1)
```

This is because for `R=X*X'`, the `d`-th off-diagonal has these elements:

```
R(k,k+d) = sum (X(k,:) .* X(k+d,:))
```